# Encontrar o índice em um vetor de dicionários baseado no valor

Tags: python

Se eu tiver um array de dicionários e quiser encontrar o índice no array de um determinado valor do dicionário, como eu faço?

Ex:

```
palavra1 = {'palavra': 'valor1'}
palavra2 = {'palavra': 'valor2'}
palavras = [palavra1, palavra2]
```

Caso eu queira encontrar qual é o índice em 'palavras' que corresponda a 'valor2', como eu devo proceder?

Answer (score 0):

Pra verificar se o valor da chave 'palavra' corresponde a 'valor2':

```
palavra1.get('palavra') == 'valor2'  # True
```

Isso evita que você tenha um `KeyError` por acessar uma chave que não existe.

Sabendo isso, você pode fazer um loop que itera sob sua lista e para quando encontra um resultado válido:

```
palavra1 = {'palavra': 'valor1'}
palavra2 = {'palavra': 'valor2'}
palavras = [palavra1, palavra2]

for indice, palavra in enumerate(palavras):
    if palavra.get('palavra') == 'valor2':
        break

print('Indice:', indice)  # 1
print('Palavra:', palavra)  #  {'palavra': 'valor2'}
```

Você também pode fazer o mesmo com uma expressão geradora:

```
palavra1 = {'palavra': 'valor1'}
palavra2 = {'palavra': 'valor2'}
palavras = [palavra1, palavra2]

indice, palavra = next((i, p) for i, p in enumerate(palavras) if p.get('palavra') == 'valor2')
print('Indice:', indice)  # 1
print('Palavra:', palavra)  #  {'palavra': 'valor2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

O mesmo valor pode estar contido em vários elementos da sua lista de dicionários. Uma solução seria montar uma lista contendo o índice de cada elemento/dicionario no qual o valor foi encontrado, veja só:

```
palavra1 = {'palavra': 'valor1'}
palavra2 = {'palavra': 'valor2'}
palavra3 = {'palavra': 'valor3'}
palavra4 = {'palavra': 'valor1'}

palavras = [ palavra1, palavra2, palavra3, palavra4 ]

idxlst = [i for i, d in enumerate(palavras) if d["palavra"] == "valor1"]

print( idxlst )
```

Saída:

```
[0, 3]
```